# React test: after update input the props value still not change

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I have this code in test

```
let formatField = subject.find("input").at(0);
(formatField.props() as any).onChange({
     currentTarget: { value: "Potato" }
});
```

The problem is after this action when I get `formatField.props().value` it still `undefined`

Do I missing something?

I tried with

```
formatField .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Potato' } });
```

and also

```
formatField .simulate('keydown', { keyCode: 13 });
```

the value still not update

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show a complete component?

Comment: @FrankAK it is an very simple component with an input in it https://plnkr.co/edit/NIsfKMeVyY3gDw4aabOL?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it by my self: need to wait for it update

```
const waitForAsync = () => new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
await waitForAsync();
subject.update();
```

also the simulate change event should like this

```
 formatField.simulate("change", {
        target: { value: "my value" }
      });
```